# Unable to install November update on my Win 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm running `Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.10240`.

I noticed that my Windows Update is yet to show any signs of the November update, but I found out that you can manually upgrade by navigating to here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

and clicking the `Upgrade now` button. I clicked the button and the following application was downloaded:

`GetWindows10-sds_____________.exe`

Each time I execute the above application, a new instance of Edge is opened and I'm taken to the same website as before:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

This happens every time I execute the app, or try to download another copy of the app and execute that.

I've had Win 10 installed on my PC for longer than 31 days, so that constraint does not apply to me.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Enterprise version of this update/patch is on its way.

Comment: I'm burning an ISO as we speak - I'm impatient :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I didn't read the small print on that web page:

> the media creation tool and the Upgrade now button above won’t work
>   for an upgrade. Please see the Volume Licensing Service Center for
>   more information.